# LibreOffice 5.4 not using GTK3

Tags: 16.04, gnome, libreoffice, gtk, gtk3

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and using LibreOffice 5.4.3.2.

The program doesn't use GTK3, no matter what I try. I tried setting the `SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN`-variable to `gtk3` and I even reinstalled the whole package. However, nothing works.

Does anybody know how to solve this?